# serialize function hover on animation fiddle Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm animating thosefacebook stickers

**PROBLEM**

The code works perfectly if I work with a single animation. Once I start adding more animations:

1) hovering on one animation, activates all the animations (expected: animate this especific animation only)

2) the function gets the value of the first data attribute of the first div match, so the next divs doesnt animate with its corresponding number of frames of its `data-frame` attribute value (those white gaps on the animation)

**EXPECTED**

I want to hover on each image and animate it for 3 seconds....then stop it. Not the anothers

I know I have to use `$(this)` but still dont figure out how to bind it with the elements

```js
var currentY = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var isAnimating = false;
var $Sticker = $('.Sticker');
var StickerWidth = $Sticker.data("swidth");
var frameRateMs = 120;
var totalNumberOfFrames = $Sticker.data("frames");
var currentFrame = 1;


function animateSticker() {

  if (isAnimating) {
    $Sticker.css({
      'background-position': currentX + 'px ' + currentY + "px"
    });
    if (currentFrame == totalNumberOfFrames) {
      currentX = 0;
      currentY = 0;
    } else if (currentX > -StickerWidth * 3) {
      currentX -= StickerWidth;
    } else {
      currentY -= StickerWidth;
      currentX = 0;
    }
    currentFrame = currentFrame < totalNumberOfFrames ? currentFrame + 1 : 1;

  }
  setTimeout(animateSticker, frameRateMs);
}

 let AnimationStickerTimer;
$(document).on("click mouseover touchstart", ".Sticker",function() {
isAnimating = true;
        clearTimeout(AnimationStickerTimer);
         AnimationStickerTimer = setTimeout(function() {isAnimating = false;}, 3000);
})

//$(".Sticker").trigger("mouseover");

animateSticker();
```

```css
.Sticker {
    display:inline-block;
 margin:10px auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.Sticker1 {
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/10173492_451580794986026_682840851_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=c07985ac69f96c2a6c565f5b0d74ee7f&oe=5B690617");
}

.Sticker2 {
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/851562_396469960497110_526457688_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=3c32526672caa6dd3c362338b2cc559b&oe=5B55A0AF");
}
.Sticker3 {
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p160x160/10333116_451580828319356_731553959_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=ad633d10f4a0b1fa7de80737cb7caa14&oe=5B65F2FE");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Sticker Sticker1" data-frames="12" data-swidth="80"></div>
<div class="Sticker Sticker2" data-frames="10" data-swidth="80"></div>

<div class="Sticker Sticker3" data-frames="4" data-swidth="64"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$Sticker` value using  `$Sticker = $(this);` like this.

```js
var currentY = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var isAnimating = false;
var $Sticker = $('.Sticker');
var StickerWidth = $Sticker.data("swidth");
var frameRateMs = 120;
var totalNumberOfFrames = $Sticker.data("frames");
var currentFrame = 1;


function animateSticker() {

  if (isAnimating) {
    $Sticker.css({
      'background-position': currentX + 'px ' + currentY + "px"
    });
    if (currentFrame == totalNumberOfFrames) {
      currentX = 0;
      currentY = 0;
    } else if (currentX > -StickerWidth * 3) {
      currentX -= StickerWidth;
    } else {
      currentY -= StickerWidth;
      currentX = 0;
    }
    currentFrame = currentFrame < totalNumberOfFrames ? currentFrame + 1 : 1;

  }
  setTimeout(animateSticker, frameRateMs);
}

 let AnimationStickerTimer;
$(document).on("click mouseover touchstart", ".Sticker",function() {
$Sticker = $(this); // Change and add this line
isAnimating = true;
        clearTimeout(AnimationStickerTimer);
         AnimationStickerTimer = setTimeout(function() {isAnimating = false;}, 3000);
})

//$(".Sticker").trigger("mouseover");

animateSticker();
```

```css
.Sticker {
    display:inline-block;
 margin:10px auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.Sticker1 {
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/10173492_451580794986026_682840851_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=c07985ac69f96c2a6c565f5b0d74ee7f&oe=5B690617");
}

.Sticker2 {
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p240x240/851562_396469960497110_526457688_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=3c32526672caa6dd3c362338b2cc559b&oe=5B55A0AF");
}
.Sticker3 {
    background: url("https://scontent.flim5-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.1997-6/p160x160/10333116_451580828319356_731553959_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=ad633d10f4a0b1fa7de80737cb7caa14&oe=5B65F2FE");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Sticker Sticker2" data-frames="10" data-swidth="80"></div>
<div class="Sticker Sticker1" data-frames="12" data-swidth="80"></div>
<div class="Sticker Sticker3" data-frames="4" data-swidth="64"></div>
```

Comment: WOW, I just cant believe I was one line close of the result. I knew I had to add a `$(this)` line but I didnt know where....awesome thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help happy coding :)

Comment: it was needed to add `totalNumberOfFrames = $Sticker.data("frames"); ` below your added line to make the animation get the correct number of frames, to avoid the white gaps while animating, now is perfect!!